# How to make a Button expand to show its Text in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

I have created a `Style` for my Buttons but when I use longer texts, *they are truncated*.

This is the style:

```
<Style x:Key="DefaultButton" TargetType="Button">
        <!--<Setter Property="WidthRequest">
            <Setter.Value>
                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                         Phone="150"
                         Tablet="200" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="HeightRequest">
            <Setter.Value>
                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                         Phone="70"
                         Tablet="100" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>-->
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource BaseColor}" />
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalOptions" Value="CenterAndExpand" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize">
            <Setter.Value>
                <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                         Phone="20"
                         Tablet="25" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The button:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Style="{DynamicResource DefaultButton}"
        Text="Basic button with long text" />
```

This is how that button with a longer text looks:

[image]

I could set a very large `HeightRequest` for the button but that would be very bad practice.

What should I do about this?

Comment: You could always omit setting the height request and let the button size itself. Is there any reason you have to set it explicitly?

Comment: @WilliamCorncobDecker You might have misunderstood me. I do not want to set the HeigthRequest explicitly (it is commented out), I'd like it to be auto sized. How can I do it?

Comment: four years latter I'm having the same issue with XF 4.6.0.726

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I will often used a `Grid` with a `BoxView` and a `Label` to make up the button and then put a `GestureRecognizer` on the `Grid`. Add all of this to a custom control for easy reuse if you want.

I did the `GestureRecognizer` below from memory so it might need some fixing:

```
<Grid x:Name="BasicButtonGrid"
      VerticalOptions="End">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Grid.MinimumHeightRequest>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
             Phone="40"
             Tablet="70"/>
  </Grid.MinimumHeightRequest>

  <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnBasicButtonTapped"/>
  </Grid.GestureRecognizers>

  <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue"
           VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
           InputTransparent="True"
           Grid.Row="0"
           Grid.Column="0"/>

  <Label Text="Basic Button with long text"
         TextColor="White"
         FontSize="Medium"
         Grid.Row="0"
         Grid.Column="0"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `LineBreakMode`property. Here is the documentation to help you choose the most suitable mode.

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.LineBreakMode/

Comment: There is no `LineBreakMode` property in the Button class.